# My NodeJS http POST request to calculate a sum of a json value does't work

Tags: node.js, json, express

I'm new to NodeJS, and I'm doing an exercise to calculate the sum of a JSON value I entered in a POST request, but postman gives me an error message

> "Cannot POST /add".

A I missing something? Here is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const math = require('mathjs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

const host = "127.0.0.1"
const port = 3000

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

async function add(tal) {
    let promise = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/apiServer/add', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(tal) }
    )
    let summa = math.sum(promise);
    return summa;
}

app.post('apiServer/add', (req, res) => {
    var tal = req.body.user;  
    res.send(add(tal));
});

app.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log(`The server is running at: http://${host}:${port}`);
});
```

POST:

```
{    
  "tal": "10,343,24,345,22,23,233"
}
```

Comment: The POST endpoint that you have defined is for the path: `apiServer/add`, so you should be posting to `apiServer/add`. Also, an `async` method will always return a promise, you'll need to grab the resolve value from `add()` after calling it before you send back a value

Comment: @Nick, thanks for promt reply. I tried the /add first and didn't work, then changed to 7apiServer/add.

Comment: Do you get an error when you try and POST to `apiServer/add`? Is it the same error of different

Comment: This shouldn't be `.user` but should be `.tal` instead: `var tal = req.body.user;` since the data you are sending does not seem to have a `.user` property

Comment: @Nick, with just add/, the postman is returning empty, but i'm getting a "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:" at the terminal.

Comment: Can you show the full error message?

Comment: Also, what are you trying to do with `let promise = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/apiServer/add', { ... })` ?

Comment: @NickParsons, i changed the .user wth .tal as you said, but now getting a "SyntaxError: Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0"

Comment: @NickParsons, what i'm trying to do i s to enter the post: "tal" : "10,23,45,56,34", and the my function add(), should get what i entered and calculate the sum of the values in"tal". I'm not sure though if the function will work. could you advice please!

Comment: Ok, you don't need `let promise = await fetch(...)` in your code, also, `let summa = math.sum(promise);` won't work either, so you can remove this. If you remove these two lines then your function doesn't need to be `async`, so you can remove that. Now, you need to perform your own logic to sum up the numbers in your string (hint: use `.split()` and a for loop)

Comment: @NickParsons, so you mean i remove evrything in the add(), and instead use a .split() and loop? How then will i get the "tal" i entered, to loop through?

Comment: Here is an example of what I mean, the `tal` that you entered gets passed into the `add()` function: https://jsfiddle.net/nr824bmz/

Comment: @NickParsons, thank you so much. The function works fine, i get to verify the sum with console.log().

Answer (score 0):

This function looks circular.  You are using fetch to call your own endpoint
I think you just need to create an add function as well as a get or post function to then call the add

here is an example

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

function add(num1, num2) {
    return parseFloat(num1) + parseFloat(num2);
}

app.get('/api/add', (req, res) => {
    const num1 = req.query.num1;
    const num2 = req.query.num2;
    const total = add(num1, num2);
    res.send(`The total is ${total}`);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`The server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Then you can call it in a Postman or Insomnia type app using a get like this

```
http://localhost:3000/api/add?num1=12&num2=3
```

[image]